# What is the best Practice(Method) to auto login to a website in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I had been trying to create an app with a webview in it,that auto login's the user into the website.once the user just opens it i had been using java script to auto fill the username and password column using the below javascript code in after onPageFinished method as shown in the below code.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        final String password = "xxx";
        final String username = "xxxxx";


        if(url.equals("http://www.bvrit.edu.in/")){
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:var userID =document.getElementById('txtId1').value='" + username + "';");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:var userpassword =document.getElementById('txtPwd1').value='" + password + "';");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                    "l=document.getElementById('imgBtn1');" +
                    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');" +
                    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);" +
                    "l.dispatchEvent(e);" +
                    "})()"
            );
        }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```

But,I am facing a lot of problems by using this the button click is working some times and doesn't work some other times.So is there any other way in which i can auto login to a website in a webview like using a POST method to send the fields and the load the webview with the auto logged in data or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is to do the POST request by yourself (for example, using OkHttp).

Comment: i too searched whether i can do a POST method but,what i had learnt is we can do a post method but cant load the result in the webview,that wouldnt work for me and correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: In this case, you must check how the website does the authentication. It may be, for example, a token in a session variable. So if it is the case, you do the authentication via POST, get the token if is valid, and shows the webview setting the corresponding header to this token.

Comment: As i am new to webTechnologies as well as android.I don't know how to check for the token in the website.If possible could u please help me out with the sessin token the website is-www.bvrit.edu.in